# Save a GET result in global variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

I have an API, and I call it via JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON('../api/Config/email')
    .done(function (data) {
        statusUpdate("icon16", "success " + data.Data);
    }).fail(function (status) {
        statusUpdate("icon16", "Error " + status.statusText);
    });
```

I don't have issue to display the value of in data.Data

But I would like use the result of the api call in other position in my code. So I would like save the value of my variable data.Data

Something like:

```
    var myData;
    $.getJSON('../api/Config/email')
        .done(function (data) {
            statusUpdate("icon16", "success " + data.Data);
            myData = data.Data;
        }).fail(function (status) {
            statusUpdate("icon16", "Error " + status.statusText);
        });
        statusUpdate("icon16", "success " + myData);
```

But this didn't work. And I don't know how save my data outside of my function done.

Comment: Do you want to use it on a different page, or from a different location in the same page?

Comment: There's no problem saving something to a variable in a wider scope. The problem is *when* you save it. myData will only get data after your async function returns.

Comment: make sure that myData is in global scope, meaning outside of any functions